# How to extract values from Ansible gather facts and manipulate it?

Tags: ansible-facts

I want to extract some values from gather facts `{{ ansible_default_ipv4 }}`
In order to do so I ran `ansible -i hosts all -m setup -a filter=ansible_default_ipv4`
Then I get the output as:

```
"ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_default_ipv4": {
            "address": "10.6.97.221",
            "alias": "bond0",
            "broadcast": "10.6.97.255",
            "gateway": "10.6.97.1",
            "interface": "bond0",
            "macaddress": "e8:39:35:c0:38:a4",
            "mtu": 1500,
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
            "network": "10.6.97.0",
            "type": "ether"
        },
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false
```

I want to extract the values from address + netmask + gateway and print them in that value to a file.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve it by

```
- name: echo
  shell: echo "{{ ansible_hostname }} {{ ansible_default_ipv4.macaddress }} {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ ansible_default_ipv4.netmask}} {{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway}} {{ SERVER_ILO.stdout }}" >> /tmp/log.txt
```